# Calculate conditional probability when having samples from the multivariate normal distribution in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, probability, gaussian, sample

I am working in R and have a matrix (200X3) named X where I have simulated data from a multivariate normal distribution given its parameters (variance-covariance matrix & and mu). My task is to calculate conditional probabilities P(X1>1/X2=1, X3=-2) and P(X1>1/X2+X3=-1)where X1,X2 and X3 the 1st,2nd and 3rd columns of X. I would really appreciate some tips.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Well, do you know mathematically how to do that? That sounds more like a statistics homework question than a programming question. if you need help with statistics, you should ask your question at [stats.se] instead. Questions here should have a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input, desired output, and your code attempts thus far. R is more of a calculator rather than a magic statistics machine; you need to clearly tell it what you want to compute.

Comment: Well I suppose i could use Bayes theorem, but still i dont know how to calculate probability of a joint distribution in R when my samples are from a multivariate normal distribution

Comment: The conditional distribution of any subset of jointly Gaussian variables is again Gaussian, with mean and variance derived from the joint distribution. It's a standard result; I seem to recall seeing it in Chapter VIII of "Theory of Probability" by R. von Mises. A web search should find the formula.

Comment: appreciate the tip, will look online for this book, thanks a lot!